# How can I configure Pytest cli options for a specific file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using the pytest-parallel library which I need to use in a specific file. The problem is that using this library causes other tests to fail because they cannot be used in parallel. What I need is some method to configure the pytest cli options in a specific file and not globally.

```bash
pytest --workers auto
```

I need to use `--workers auto` for a specific file, not for all the python files I have in the test folder.

I suppose there should be a method to specify in pytest.ini the cli options for a specific file but I have not found anything in the documentation.
One solution would be to have the tests that can be run in parallel in one folder and the ones that cannot be run in parallel in a different folder, when trying to run the unit tests I would have to run pytest twice, but I am looking if there is a way to have everything in the same folder and that each file has different configurations.

Comment: I'm afraid that PyTest does not offer per-suite configuration, only global.